# Ignite Spring Data support implementation & Spring Data REST support

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, ignite, spring-data-rest, gridgain

I am wondering if the Ignite Spring Data implementation has plans (or is it already supposed to work) to support the Spring Data REST higher level project. I know from their docs (Spring Data) that the current support is available only for Spring Data JPA, MongoDB, Neo4j, Solr, Cassandra, Gemfire.

From what i understand from a quick look at the Ignite Spring Data implementation it doesn't appear to fall under any Spring Data category including Spring Data JDBC (please correct me if i am wrong) let alone JPA (BTW, it would be awesome if it did).

Hence the question on the support & the plan.

UPDATE (Sept 21, 2020):

If Ignite's implementation does implement the Spring Data JDBC contract then why did the implementation require a separate, unrelated '@EnableIgniteRepositories' to configure repositories instead of adhering to the standard '@EnableJdbcRepositories' defined by the Spring Data JDBC project.

This made me doubt what the implementation intended to be..meaning does it want to be a separate project implementing parts of the spec or does it want to implement the Spring Data JDBC or the even better Spring Data JPA contract.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think SO is the right place to ask about Spring's support and plans. You should ask it on Spring's respective channel(s).

Comment: Thanks @Madhu Bhat but this is not regarding Spring's support but rather the expected implementation behavior of Apache Ignite..in terms of its support for a sub project of Spring...and since we have several ignite folks here who have in the past been very helpful & quick to clarify things i thought i can continue here itself..hope its ok.

Answer (score 1):

Since Apache Ignite is a SQL database along other things, you should be able to use it with Spring Data JDBC.

Ignite Spring Data implements Repository interface of Spring Data to hold POJOs in its caches in document oriented mode.

Comment: Thanks @alamar, i expected so aswell but then i got this question, if Ignite's implementation does implement the Spring Data JDBC contract then why did the implementation require a separate, unrelated '@EnableIgniteRepositories' to configure repositories instead of adhering to the standard '@EnableJdbcRepositories' defined by the Spring Data JDBC project. This made me doubt what the implementation intended to be..meaning does it want to be a separate project implementing parts of the spec or does it want to implement the Spring Data JDBC or the even better Spring Data JPA contract..

Comment: As I have said, it is a separate implementation, and you should be able to use Spring Data JDBC without any extra modules (just provide Ignite JDBC driver)

Comment: OK let me understand it right, do you mean that Ignite implements/supports BOTH the Spring Data JDBC and a separate Spring Data Ignite project? So one could enable & use ignite repositories even by using '@EnableJdbcRepositories' & use it as per the JDBC contract? If so, it would be good to know the intent & plan for the latter (Spring Data Ignite implementation that is referred to in the ignite docs).

Comment: We did not test that, but it should work. Just pass `IgniteJdbcThinDataSource` to it. Make sure to share your experience on user mailing list.

Comment: Sure @alamar, actually we are already using the latter & did not know of the former until now...its good to know..will try when i get a chance & share the findings in the mailing list. But again, going back to the original question, i would vote for the Spring Data JPA support since that gives the nice Spring Data REST higher level project support unless the plan is for doing that with the current Spring Data Ignite implementation..

Comment: Well, Apache Ignite supports Spring Data JPA (the default one) as far as my understanding goes.

Comment: Hi @alamar, as far as i know based on past issues with attempting to use myself JPA queries i was given to understand that Spring Data JPA is not supported..i think it was one of my SO questions..if we do it would be better to update the ignite documentation as its very useful for a lot of folks...may be i will email in the user mailing list..

Comment: https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/spring-data -  there's this, I'm not sure which specific Spring Data flavor this is.
Maybe you can use JCache (JSR107) which is supported by Ignite natively in place of JPA?

Comment: that's what we are already using today (which i referred to as 'Spring Data Ignite implementation' earlier), its not Spring Data JPA...

Comment: If you look at the code or ignite docs [link you noted](https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/spring-data), it clearly notes "Apache Ignite implements Spring Data [CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true) interface that not only supports basic CRUD operations but also provides access.." If it were to support Spring Data JPA it would have had to implement [JpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html)